# How to replace a line (directory path) with a variable containing another line (new directory path) in a Linux file?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a file containing contents like:

```
aaaaaaaaaa
export ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/test/prod/db_1
bbbbbbbbbb
```

Now I want to replace the line of

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/test/prod/db_1
```

with something like below:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11204/dbhome_1
```

I tried numerous ways found through Google like using "sed" or "awk" but neither one worked.  I tried:

```
export D1="export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11204/dbhome_1"
sed -i -e "s+export ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/test/prod/db_1+$D1+" file.lst
```

Note: as one Google search says, since the strings contains "/", so a different delimiter like "+" needs to be used.

Can you share with me the right command to do so?

Comment: if your `file.lst` has touched a Windows environment, (wordpad, ftp, anything!), AND you doing your change in a *nix environment, then remove `Ctrl-M` chars at lineendings with `dos2unix file.lst`. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It's a file created on Linux system, it can be any Linux type file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are still having trouble with the substitution, you can use this variation which will explicitly find the line containing `export ORACLE_HOME` before attempting the path substitution. The expression makes use of alternate delimiters for the substitution `'|'`.

To edit in place (Linux), you can use the `'-i'` option (and add `'-i.bak'` to make a backup of the original). If you are using a mac or other OS without the `'-i'` option available, use redirection to create a new file which you can copy over the current file.

```
sed -i '/^export\sORACLE_HOME/s|=.*$|=/u01/app/oracle/product/11204/dbhome_1|' \
yourfilename
```

or without `'-i'`:

```
sed '/^export\sORACLE_HOME/s|=.*$|=/u01/app/oracle/product/11204/dbhome_1|' \
yourfilename > newfilename
cp yourfilename yourfilename.sav && mv -f newfilename yourfilename
```

(*note:* the `'\'` at the end of the `sed` command line is a simple line-continuation)

---

**Using a Variable for Replacement**

From your comment, if you want to use a variable instead of a hardcoded path for the replacement string, then simply replace the single-quotes with double-quotes and include the variable as the replacement string. For example:

```
npath=/u01/app/oracle/product/11204/dbhome_1
sed -i "/^export\sORACLE_HOME/s|=.*$|=$npath|" dat/opath.txt
```

Comment: David, thank you very much for your help.  The command works, but in my case I want to use variable rather than "/u01/app/oracle/product/11204/dbhome_1".  So that when the script is executed, I can enter the new directory path on the command line.

Comment: I updated the answer, the primary change needed was from single to double quotes, and then simply include the variable as the replacement string.

Comment: David, again, thank you very much for your updates.  It works!!!!! Why use /^    --- why need "\s"  in "\sORACLE_HOME"?   --- Does " =.*$ "  between the 2 pipes/vertical bar means replacing texts after "export ORACLE_HOME=" ?

Comment: The `^` just anchors the search to the beginning of the line. It just protects against a match if you have a line later like a comment or something that has `# environment export ORACLE_HOME sets the path`, etc. The *carrot* (properly *circumflex*) just makes sure it only matches a line that starts with the phrase.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r 's~(ORACLE_HOME=).*~\1new/path/here~'
```

here `~` is used as the delimiter.  If the new path is a bash variable, you can escape the quotes

```
sed -r 's~(ORACLE_HOME=).*~\1'$D1'~'
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried and got following error:  cat test.lst |sed -r 's~(ORACLE_HOME=).*~\1'$d1'~'                                                                                                                 
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unterminated `s' command

Comment: how's your `$d1` defined?

Comment: export D1="export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11204/dbhome_1"

Comment: After I change 's  to "s  and end with double quote, I got: sed -r "s~(ORACLE_HOME=).*~\1'$D1'~" test.lst
export ORACLE_HOME='export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11204/dbhome_1'   =============================================  but I want the whole line to be replaced with the value of D1

Comment: I wanted to minimize typing, you can follow your original search/replace with quotes handled.

Comment: What is the purpose of " .* "? <br> I used cut to remove the redundant "export ORACLE_HOME":  <br>  sed -r "s~(export ORACLE_HOME=).*~\1$D1~" test.lst |cut -d'=' -f2-3 <br> 
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11204/dbhome_1